# Looking for icon shop

Tags: asp.net, html, icons

I'm looking for nice icons for my webapplications. Some of these applications are commercial applications. I want to polish them up by using nice looking icons, but where do I find specific icons/grafics?

Does anybody know a icon shop, that allows me to buy single icons for commercial use? Payable via paypal or credit card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this site: http://www.777icons.com

Answer (score 3):

http://www.iconfinder.com has a lot of icons (with different licenses)

Answer (score 1):

These two sites provide some nice icons.

http://dryicons.com - some free / some to purchase

http://www.iconpot.com/ - free icons

HTH

Barry

Answer (score 1):

you can also buy them on [www.istockphoto.com](http://www.istockphoto.com) most are in packs but you can contact the designers by clicking their names and getting their details for single icons.

Answer (score 1):

Did you know Visual Studio comes with a library of images and icons? See C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\VS2010ImageLibrary.

[Visual Studio Image Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247035(VS.100).aspx) on MSDN.
A blog post, [Tips and Tricks: Visual Studio 2010 Image Library](http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/29/tips-and-tricks-visual-studio-2010-image-library.aspx).

Maybe you can find something useful there before getting out the creditcard. :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.icojoy.com/ Not my, but my friends. They can make icons to order if you want.